# Stop Pivot Chart from changing Formatting on Refresh

Tags: excel-pivot

I have a line Pivot Chart. I have smoothed the lines. But when ever I use a slicer, it retains the smoothed line on the series I've sliced by, but when I clear the slicer, the other series come back without the smoothed line.

How do I force a Pivot Table to retain the formatting?